# Handle error from MVC controller in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

How to return error as JSON from server in MVC and handle this error in jqGrid?
In controller I use this

```
throw new Exception("message");
```

And in jqGrid I use

```
loadError: Error
////
```

And my function

```
function Error(xhr, st, err) {
            console.log(xhr.responseMessage);
        }
```

But there is a html code in xhr.responseMessage, and I need just my error message.

Answer (score 1):

Server side

```
try {
    // some processing
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    return Json(new { Message = e.Message});
}
```

jqGrid

```
loadError: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a small tweak to Wilts C's answer:

**Server side**

```
try {
    // some processing
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    return Json(new { Message = e.Message});
}
```

**jqGrid**

```
loadError: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(xhr.responseJSON.Message || "There was an unhandled problem!");
}
```